# Prevent WhatsApp from playing notification sound

Tags: android, event-handling, notifications, hook, whatsapp

maybe you know the problem, you're in a whatsapp group with many notifications about messages you don't care about.

To prevent turning off all notifications/sounds, how can i catch/hook the notifcation event from whatsapp, and maybe even discard a notification in the top bar ?

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You cannot monitor, control, override and dismiss notifications from another app in your own app.

However, in the WhatsApp specific case, you can mute the group from within the WhatsApp app, or even turn off group notifications entirely.

Comment: It should be possible with root / cyanogen, right ? I mean, as long it's my phone, i decide who's allowed to annoy me.

Comment: @siboney Not with notifications, I don't think so. You could perhaps write to their preference file to disable them if you're rooted.

Comment: At least for my phone, this answer is wrong: you can enable WhatsApp notifications and disable sound for them.